# Connectedness of the orthonormal frame bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connectedness, principal-bundles

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian connected manifold of dimension $m$ and let $O(M)$ be its orthonormal frame bundle. I would like to show that $O(M)$ is connected when $M$ is non-orientable.

My idea was to use parallel transport. I know that (Sharpe, Differential Geometry, Chap. 1, Corollary 1.18) $M$ is orientable if and only if, at a given point $p\in M$, all the loops $\lambda:[0,1]\longrightarrow M$ such that $\lambda(0)=\lambda(1)=p$ are orientation-preserving. Since $M$ is non-orientable, there exists a loop $\bar{\lambda}$ with base point $p$ which is orientation-reversing: this means that, given $X_1,...,X_m$ vector fields along $\bar{\lambda}$ such that $B_0=\{X_1(0),...,X_m(0)\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$, the determinant of the transformation between $B_0$ and the orthonormal basis $B_1=\{X_1(1),...,X_m(1)\}$ is negative. This implies that there exists a path between the points $(p,X_1(0),...,X_m(0))$ and $(p,X_1(1),...,X_m(1))$ of $O(M$). I have some questions, though:

1. Did I do some mistakes in this part of the proof?
2. How could I extend this argument (if it is right) to all the paths $\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$
   and $\gamma(1)=q$, in order to show that **all** points in $O(M)$ can be connected?
3. What happens when $M$ is oriented?

Comment: The key piece of information to use is that $SO(n)$ is connected, and any two consistently oriented orthonormal bases of $T_p M$ differ by an element of $SO(n)$. (Equivalently, $O(M)/SO(n)=C(M)$, where $C(M)$ is the oriented double cover.)

Comment: @Kajelad I am a bit confused. I know that $M$ is non-orientable if and only if $C(M)$ is connected, but does this assure that $O(M)$ is connected? And how can I extend your argument about $SO(m)$ to all the tangent spaces?

Comment: First you show that any two points in the same fiber of $O(M)$ are connected (using connectedness of $SO(n)$ and your construction). Connectedness of $M$ does the rest, since we can lift paths from $M$ to $O(M)$.

Comment: Alternately, given a quotient manifold $Y=X/G$ for a free and proper $G$-action on $X$, one can show that if $Y$ and $G$ are connected, then so is $X$.

Comment: @Kajelad So, basically, the choice of a loop on $M$ which reverses the orientation is equivalent to a choice of a path in $SO(m)$ which connects two non consistently oriented bases of $T_pM$. Then, I can lift a path in $M$ to a path in $O(M)$ and connect all the bases. If $M$ is oriented, since every loop is orientation preserving, every path in $SO(m)$ connects consistently oriented bases, thus $O(M)$ has two connected components. Is this right?

Comment: Almost: For one, an orientation-reversing path in $M$ lifts to a path in $O(M)$, not $SO(n)$; otherwise the argument seems fine. For the converse, the argument you give isn't quite sufficient; you can instead assume $O(M)$ is connected, and show $M$ is nonorientable by constructing an orientation reversing loop.